# $|G| = mn$ where $gcd(m,n) = 1$ then there exist normal subgroups $H$, $K$ such that $|H| = m$ and $|K| = n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

If we have a finite group $G$ such that $|G| = mn$, and $gcd(m,n) = 1$, then I would like to show there exist normal subgroups $H$, $K$ such that $|H| = m$ and $|K| = n$. I do not know, that this is necessarily even true, though. I want to show this because I need to show that any element $g \in G$ can be decomposed into $g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$. This would follow very quickly if I could show that such an $H$ and $K$ exist, but I am not sure if they even do exist.

Comment: Do dihedral groups of order $2p$ ($p>2$ is a prime) have a normal subgroup of order $2$?

Comment: $A_5$ is simple (no normal subgroups) and so, has no normal subgroups of order, say, $m=5, n=12$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the decomposition into $g_1 g_2=g_2 g_1$? What are $g_1$ and $g_2$?

Comment: $g_1 , g_2$ are elements of $G$ so I mean $g = g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$ where $g, g_1, g_2 \in G$

Comment: By Hall's Theorem (which generalizes Sylow's Theorems), this is always possible (for any factorization of $|G|$ into relatively prime integers) if and only if $G$ is solvable.